# Duplicate when creating a blog entity using an existing gallery in sonata admin

Tags: gallery, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I'm currently using Sonata Admin. I have a Blog entity that links to a sonata-media-bundle Gallery entity.

I created a Blog object B1 with gallery G1. This is OK

I then tried to create a Blog object B2 using the same gallery G1. Error for duplicates reasons.

#### The Blog Entity

```
/**
 * Blog
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ACME\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\BlogRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Blog
{
    ...

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $images;

    ...
}
```

#### In my admin

```
/**
 * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
            ->add('title', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('author', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('blog', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('taxonomy', null, array('required' => true))
        ->end()
        ->with('Images')
            ->add('images', 'sonata_type_model', array('multiple' => false, 'required' => false))
        ->end()
        ->with('System Information', array('collapsed' => true))
            ->add('created')
            ->add('updated')
            ->add('published')
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

Anyone here can explain why I get the following error when trying to reuse an existing Gallery object?

**Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_6027FE7DD44F05E5'**

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found why.

The **OneToOne** relationship is creating a unicity constraint.

Replacing **OneToOne** by **ManyToOne** fixed it:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery")
```